# UILabel does not wrap (if I change default font size)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, storyboard, uilabel

I am working on a simple **storyboard** prototype. My TableViewController uses Dynamic Prototype as Content.

I have a cell with 4 label of which two will be set in code (the label text). The height of the cell will be calculated in code too. The Line Breaks are set to Word Wrap and **everything's working fine with the default values (System 17.0)**:

*see here:*

[image]

..but if I **change the Font Size of the "Fantasy Street..." label** it will not break any more instead it just will be cut off!

*see here: with System Font 16*

[image]

Lines are set to 0
Word Wrap is still active

.. I also tried to do it manually in code but no change.

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

****edited:** when I add 
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(t.origin.x, t.origin.y, t.size.width, t.size.height *2);

to the cellForRowAtIndexPath I still see the cut off label. But if I then scroll the table view so the label is outside the viewable area shortly it will be displayed with the complete text when it is visible again.

By the way, I am working with viewTags, so I don't have a dedicated Cell Class e.g. UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

Comment: could you please try to increase the hight of UILabel ?

Comment: do you mean the frame of the UILabel ? I already tried that. I think it s so weird.

Comment: could it be the auto layout getting in the way?  If your cell is set up in storyboard, auto layout calls coud be messing with your view when things change.

Comment: if I deselect Autolayout, but still have the myLabel setFrame invocation in code the label is rendered completely but unfortunately at another position (could fix that in code I think). But what s the best practice for my problem? Using a Custom Cell Class? I guess it s a bug with the Autolayout huh?!

Comment: I'm guessing you increased the apparent font size slightly such that there's no longer room for the second line.  In any event, note that there are several label properties that affect string folding, font size adjustment, et al, and sizeToFit can be used to force the label to resize to fit the string (though sometimes the results are "surprising").

Comment: (Question:  Which did you set first -- font size or "text"?  Try reversing the order.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: I am decreasing the default fonts size (via IB), sizeToFit won't solve it neither. I also tried to set the font in code and reversed the order ( with setting the text) - no change

Comment: As it seems that autolayout has sty. to do with it I think the cell/label is not painted correctly. When the cell disappears while scrolling and reappears again I think the cell is repainted again, right? As I wrote before, when it reappears it is rendered correctly

Comment: I notice that "Adresse:" has moved, suggesting that the height of the label has physically changed.

Comment: Yes exactly but only if I don't change the Font size. The first example uses the default settings (freshly created) I think its System Font with size 17. Then I just changed the size to 16 (statically in IB) and then it doesn t work any more.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is not solved yet. I followed Jbryson s advice of removing autolayout. I don t know if it s a bug or not but it is easily reproducible

Answer (score 1):

You should check UILabel width; the width should be less than that of the value. Then like this:

```
(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    _landPhoneTips.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = _landPhoneTips.bounds.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend using the built-in post preview in future to make sure your answers are easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours dealing with this identical problem before finally sorting it out last evening. After changing the font size, you must select the `UILabel` within the storyboard and select `Edit > Size` to Fit Content, even if you had already previously done so! In doing so you apparently reset some setting that gets messed up when changing the font size. Once done, the UILabel will wrap as it did previously.